# Convert Binary Data to Date

Tags: type-conversion, binary-data

I have the following data: F0 60 5B 50 BB 27 C4 01

I am 99% certain that this represents the date: 21/04/2004 17:11:33

I cannot for the life of me work out how it is encoding it. Am I being dense? I've tried just reading it in as a binary date, but that comes back with a date way in the future. I've tried assuming it's number of ticks since some epoch, but to no avail.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

**Edit:** The data is from an export of an application over which I have no control. I am trying to extract data from this dump in order to make reporting of the contents of the application a little easier.

Another sample is: 90 53 EC 85 CB B2 C5 01 -> 06/09/2005 11:12:44

I'm only about 50 sure that this date is correct (which is why I didn't include it previously).

Comment: It would help if you could tell us where the data is coming from.

Comment: ...or add a some more values so that we could see a pattern, if any,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I'm onto something. If you reverse bytes (so that they read `01 C4 27 BB ...` and feed that into `DateTime.FromBinary`, you'll get `21.04.0404 16:11:33`, which is very close digit-wise to your date.

Comment: Thanks. I am surprised I missed this. It seems obvious now. A lot of other things about the file are starting to make sense too.